# Flutter: Convert URI to File Path

Tags: flutter, path, uri

I have a File in the Download folder:

```
'/storage/emulated/0/Download/Music.mp3'
```

but in Flutter I only get the Uri like this:

```
'content://media/external/audio/media/906'
```

when is use uri_to_file Plugin, I get a temporary file name:

```
'/data/data/com.myapp.testapp/files/uri_to_file/Music.mp3'
```

How can I get the real path in the Download folder ???

Thanks so much!

Comment: the answer is simple: you cannot do that, more here: https://commonsware.com/community/t/get-file-from-uri/624

Comment: also this can be useful: https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html

Comment: But when I want to edit metatags I need the absolute path?